# Error during building application with PropertyChanged.Fody

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, fody, fody-propertychanged

I have very simple project in WPF (PropertyChanged)- one view, one view model and one model. In this project I use package PropertyChanged.Fody. When I want to build this project after 10 second I get two error message:

1. Could not copy "obj\Debug\PropertyChanged.exe" to "bin\Debug\PropertyChanged.exe".Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
2. Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\PropertyChanged.exe" to "bin\Debug\PropertyChanged.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\PropertyChanged.exe' because it is being used by another process.

The only solution is:

- unload project
- delete folders bin and obj
- reload project

It is very unconfortable, but I relly want to use PropertyChanged.Fody

Comment: Sometimes the `Visual Studio Hosting Process` causes troubles. Go to the project `Properties > Debug > Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process` and un-check it. Then see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Okay converted my comment to the Answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the `Visual Studio Hosting Process` causes troubles. Go to the project `Properties > Debug > Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process` and un-check it.

Comment: it did not solove my problem

Comment: i followed your steps ti i unchecked it but i still sometimes get 

    Could not copy "obj\Debug\smth.exe" to "bin\Debug\smth.exe".Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
    Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\smth.exe" to "bin\Debug\smth.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\smth.exe' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Did you restart Studio after making the change? The changes sometimes take effect after a restart.

Comment: hey bro, i did what you have recommended, and i have not recieved this error again, thank your , vote you up :-)